# Extrapolation doesn't work in the Dope Sheet

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I can't understand why, in the *Dope Sheet*, when I try to extrapolate the rotation of my propeller (*Channel > Extrapolation Mode > Linear Extrapolation*, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) it doesn't work. It works fine in the *Graph Editor* though. What am I missing?

The file is [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/b607ed3cf15b4ab1bcadd275edb18b4a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As extrapolation works on a single channel basis, the procedure in dopesheet needs to have the object transform channels expanded and the Z euler channel selected. Then you can go to menu > Channel > extrapolation mode > Linear, or use shift E.

[image]

Comment: oh ok it makes sense, thanks  ;)